# 'Session expires' error in oauth for twitter

Tags: session, twitter, oauth

I am using abraham williams library to update twitter status using
oauth. But I am constantly getting:

> session expired

error. How can I get around this?

This is my source:

connect.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "--------------------");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "---------------------------");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken('http://127.0.0.1/callback.php');

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] =
$request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

$url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($request_token);
header('Location: ' . $url);
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
header('Location: ./connect.php');
}

require_once 'twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "---------------");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "--------------------------------");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(
  CONSUMER_KEY,
  CONSUMER_SECRET,
  $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'],
  $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret']
);

include("form.php");
$msg = $_POST['tweet'];

if (!empty($msg)) {
  $tweetmsg = $msg; }
else {
  exit('Post a tweet');
     }

$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $tweetmsg));
unset($_SESSION['tweetmsg']);
if (200 === $connection->http_code) {
   echo'tweet posted';
}
else {
$resultmsg = 'Could not post Tweet. Error: '.$httpCode.'  
Reason:'.$result->error;
echo $resultmsg;
}
?>
```

callback.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "---------------");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "------------------------------");

if (
  isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token'])
  && $_SESSION['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']
) {
  //echo 'Session expired';
header('Location: ./connect.php');
}
else {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth(
    CONSUMER_KEY,
    CONSUMER_SECRET,
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'],
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']
  );
  $_SESSION['access_token'] =
$connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
header('Location: index.php');

unset($_SESSION['oauth_token']);
unset($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callback.php is designed to be used once during each negotiation for an access token. Not each time you want to tweet.

I recommend breaking your code into the following three files:

connect.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "--------------------");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "---------------------------");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken('http://127.0.0.1/callback.php');

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] =
$request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

$url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($request_token);
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

callback.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "------------------");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "----------------------------");

if (
  isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) 
  && $_SESSION['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']
) {
  echo 'Session expired';
}
else {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth(
    CONSUMER_KEY,
    CONSUMER_SECRET,
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'],
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']
  );
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
  header('Location: index.php');
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['tweetmsg'])) {
    $_SESSION['tweetmsg'] = $_POST['tweet'];
  }
  header('Location: ./connect.php');
}

require_once 'twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "------------------");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "----------------------------");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(
  CONSUMER_KEY,
  CONSUMER_SECRET,
  $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'],
  $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret']
);

if (!empty($_POST['tweetmsg'])) {
  $tweetmsg = $_POST['tweetmsg'];
} elseif (!empty($_SESSION['tweetmsg'])) {
  $tweetmsg = $_SESSION['tweetmsg'];
} else {
  exit('No tweet value in session or from form');
}

$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $tweetmsg));
unset($_SESSION['tweetmsg']);
if (200 === $connection->http_code) {
  $resultmsg = 'Tweet Posted: '.$tweetmsg;
}
else {
  $resultmsg = 'Could not post Tweet. Error: '.$httpCode.' Reason: '.
  $result->error;
}
```

Comment: thanX 4 the response abraham :-)

Comment: thanX 4 the response abraham :-) I break the application exactly as you mentioned, now it raises this error:                       'Could not post Tweet. Error: 401 Reason: Could not authenticate you'.                                                            One more question is as in ur recommended breakup, there is no method to send user to Twitter for authentication so how will this work. As my application is to be used by many users to post updates to their twitter accounts.

Comment: You still have to get a request token and send the user to Twitter. I updated my response to include connect.php and a check in index.php to see if there there is an access token in the session.

Comment: thank you very much abraham ...                                       I updated the code. But now when I press authenticate button on Twitter, the error message from Twitter appears, 'Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!'.

Comment: What is the Twitter URL you land on?

Comment: I open the index.php from localhost. Logged into my Twitter account from the Twitter link it opened, allow the application from the dialog box & afterward it raises this error.

Comment: So you get redirected to Twitter ok? You authorize' the application to access your Twitter account then you get the "page doesn't exist" error? Make sure you have the callback URL set properly in $request_token = $connection->getRequestToken('http://127.0.0.1/
callback.php');. If should be the same URL as where you access index.php just with callback.php instead.

Comment: I checked the address, it was same but I deleted it & write again. Now its going to callback.php i.e.('http://127.0.0.1/callback.php') but again raising 'session expired' error. You can see the address bar reading when app is directed to callback from Twitter:                                                          'http://127.0.0.1/callback.php?oauth_token=XmqCd2oWCt96Ih22IX5viGg1fmuncA8t8R1LGe1ZOc&oauth_verifier=Hqkw2SNz64feGxsIiRRHrKMICn60ud1BOqDiwgbyEgw'

Comment: I tweaked the code a little bit. Most of the edits were after your issue however. If it still does not work then I think something is wrong with how your server handles sessions. The if that checks returns "session expired" only checks to make sure the oauth_token you return from twitter matches the existing one in the session.

Comment: Yes, the problem still persists. I am using apache 2.2.14 (IPV6 enabled) web server on windows 7. What can be workaround for it. I commented the if condition for session check, it for once work. And after that again started giving session expire error.

Comment: I made some changes in callback.php. Now its working perfectly.  Thank you very much abraham, you magnificent people for your help!!                                                              kindly see the edited callback version & suggest if some change is still required.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. It looks like stale session data was causing issues.

Comment: I have one question, I have to upload it on a server and it has to be used by many people. I have only experience of single user applications. The $tweetmsg will contain message that is 2B twitted by a user. For single user its fine but what when many people have opened application from server.

Comment: If they users are tweeting whatever they want you will have to create an HTML form and submit it to the script filling $tweetmsg with whatever they wish to tweet.

Comment: Also if my reply was the solution you were looking be sure to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I already have an HTML form that I made  earlier & it is using BASIC HTTP Authentication that now is no longer supported by Twitter. So I 1st tried to make OAuth running. Now what I am thinking 2 do is let the user enter their tweet in the form & then call this 'index.php' by 'update status' button posting their tweet to $tweetmsg, it will update their status & then I again from 'index.php' redirect user to HTML form so they can continue tweeting. This is how I am thinking it will work 4 me.I Will give u feed back if it start working that way or there is still some problem.

Comment: "stdClass Object ( [request] => /1/statuses/update.json [error] => Client must provide a 'status' parameter with a value. )". I have a strange problem. I call index.php from HTML form & get $tweet to index like $tweetmsg =($_POST['tweet']) & it raises this error. I test the value of $tweet, its received in index.php but at the line $result=$connection->post('statuses/update',array('status'=> $tweetmsg)); in index.php, its empty. Can you kindly look at index.php to see why the value passed vanished reaching here. Otherwise its working this way as I checked by assigning value in index file.

Comment: I mark it because ur answer was exactly what I was looking for i.e. to make OAuth run. & actually this is one basic part of my application.

Comment: Try `$tweetmsg = $_POST['tweet'];` and make the textarea input id/name is `tweet`. If that does not work try `$tweetmsg = $_REQUEST['tweet'];`.

Comment: it doesn't work. As I told u something happens between these lines.                                                           "if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) { -----------------$_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret']
);"                                                             $tweetmsg has value before these but no value after. I have same syntax i.e. $msg1 = ($_POST['tweet']); working in another example & yes I have both id & name property of textarea set as 'tweet'. May be when control goes to 'connect' value lost but it doesn't happen if I assign a value in index.php

Comment: I even tried to use session variable here but exactly same behavior is shown by session variable too like.                                                        $tweetmsg = $_REQUEST['tweet'];
$_SESSION['tweetmsg'] = $tweetmsg;  ---------------------------------  $result=$connection->post('statuses/update',array('status'=> $_SESSION['tweetmsg']));

Comment: $_POST is not persistent storage. If you have a user POST a form to index.php and there is no accesss_token in session they will be sent to Twitter to authenticate. When this happens the $_POST data is discarded. Either have the user authenticate before displaying a form to them or save the $_POST data in a session for when they get back from twitter.com.

Comment: @$_POST is not persistent storage..... I had think on it, is not it strange as I save the value in a local variable that is $tweetmsg & then control goes to connect.php. So value should be there when control returns. 4 that reason, I also tried to assign value after the control returrns i.e. before "$result=$connection->post('statuses/update',array('status'=> $tweetmsg ));" statement as its not necessary to get value at start. But No value is passed here from $_POST.

Comment: Unless you save it to $_SESSION or have the user resubmit the form the variables are discarded between page loads. $tweetmsg is not saved between page loads. here is some more information on sessions: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html

Comment: I have tried storing $tweetmsg value in session variable but it behaves exactly same as local variable $tweetmsg i.e. lost value after page load. If you kindly look at my edited index.php source above, it is how I am using session variable to store $teetmsg value.

Comment: My guess is that since when you return from twitter.com $_POST['tweet'] is a null value it is overwriting the stored $_SESSION['tweetmsg'] with that null value.

Comment: you are right. then how I bypass this re initialization, I had thought & experimented a lot but to no avail so far.....

Comment: can you kindly now see edited index file & see whats wrong now.In index file, I check if $_SESSION['tweetmsg'] is empty then initialized with POST['tweet'] otherwise leave if block. But still it do not show any value. Can u kindly suggest me how to do it, it has taken a lot of my time.

Comment: if (!empty($_POST['tweetmsg'])) {
      $tweetmsg = $_POST['tweetmsg'];
    } else {
      $tweetmsg = $_SESSION['tweetmsg'];
    }

Comment: I now just tried this one before reading ur message, but it gave same result. Here is code what I tried "if(!empty($_REQUEST['tweet']))
{
 $_SESSION['tweetmsg'] = $_REQUEST['tweet'];
 //print $_SESSION['tweetmsg']; 
} else 
{ $msg = $_SESSION['tweetmsg']; 
}
if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
header('Location: ./connect.php');
}
echo $msg;
//session_unset();"

Comment: I have now one question in mind. Control goes to three php files here(index.php->connect.php->call back->index.php) & all those files have session_start() statement. But in between before coming back to index.php, control also transfers to twitter.com. Whats situation with session variables at that control transfer time.

Comment: As long as the users cookie is valid and the session has not expired the session data will be there. Going to twitter.com will not change that.

Comment: exit('No tweet value in session or from form');

Comment: the problem is after "header('Location: ./connect.php');" $_SESSION['tweetmsg'] looses its value strangely. I check by "if(isset($_SESSION['tweetmsg'])) {echo"set";} else echo"no set"; results 'no set'-

Comment: I tried to pass value through setcookie() but cookie donot exist after page reload. If setting cookies is problem than session variables may be are suffering bec of it. I edited the index.php, see it to validate the test that I did.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This thing came into my mind but 4get for the time being wehn SetCookie was not set. But then why $_SESSION['tweetmsg'] results in 'not-set' after page reloaded by header. Can you give any clue I could work on as I am not finding any reason still.

Comment: I have edited the index.php & its working now. Though still I have to modify it according to how I want my application to behave but at least I have one for demonstration! You can see the edited version of it. As you can see, now as soon as user opens it, it goes to twitter login page. It has one problem now is that if I have opened a twitter page in another window, I am also signed into my account when I login through the application. & if log out from twitter from other page, the application also logs me out but the message sent doesn't raise error & sent message message is echoed.

Comment: How could I recover from that. Ideally what I want to do is to make one button for 'login with twitter', and one for send message once login. This version that now suffer session variable problem has only one button to send message that 1st time logs user in & (should) send message(by calling index.php) & then continues. This is also very fine as its simple when this session problem is recovered.  Kindly see index.php for improvement & contnue hepling me for recovering session problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you log out of twitter.com it does not effect your application. Once your applications session expires you will have to go through the authentication flow with twitter.com again but that will be infrequent and you can configure PHP to extend the amount of time before the session expires.

Comment: You are right, I mistakenly suppose that by some error. I have modified the application using two buttons, one "sign in with twitter" button that calls 'connect.php' to login user & "send message" button that calls 'index.php'. Can you kindly see the code for improvement. My application also displays previous tweets that contain a keyword using cURL. Can you kindly tell me if I have to make levels of the messages that my application displays, How to do that?Say one message thread is about operating system, & then we add one sub-level to it like Windows, Unix & each are a thread of message.

Comment: Then we add one more level to Windows like XP, VISTA etc. & these become 3rd level threads. Sub-level of each thread are available under its root like directory structure in Windows.

Comment: Check out the documentation for statuses/update. Specifically for including in_reply_to_status_id. http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update

Comment: If you have a status object like `$status` it will be the `id` attribute and it would be accessed like `$status->id`.

Comment: can you give me any clue how could I make like user clicks on any previous message & I can use its id as now I could have only last status update id available bec that is last value I have. How this message appears on twitter? Does it appears under the message whom is it a reply? I searched but did not find an example of such message.

Comment: Here is information about how replies work: http://support.twitter.com/articles/14023-what-are-replies-and-mentions